# How to fix AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the output error I get when I run my code:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "Y:/Electric Planet/Electric Planet.py", line 22, in <lambda>
    combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda event :label_selected.config(text=itemrate[item.get()]))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Comment: Are you able to share the code that causes the error please.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code, it's kind of an amateur presumption but it looks like you're trying to access `config` attribute from some object. The object seem to be holding nothing (`None`) and hence the error.

Long story short, look for variable which is trying to access `config` attribute. You need to make sure that variable is not `None`.